# Gold duplicate power didn't work

Tags: support, dupehammer

I dupe-voted this question

[Convert number to corresponding words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119088/convert-number-to-corresponding-words)

Since I have the python badge, I thought it should be closed immediately, but my vote just has been recorded like in other tags. Is that a glitch in the system or my misunderstanding on how this feature works?

Comment: The more inept the user asking the question, the greater the odds that the hammer won't work.  Or to put it another way, the system is rigged to prevent reputable users from gaming the hammer and for unreputable users to easily stop it from being used.  Optimizing for sand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gold dupe hammer only works on the question's **current** tags if you didn't edit the tags ([It looks like the duplicate banner changed. How does it work now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281#268281)), otherwise it looks at the question's **original** tags.

The question initially only had the [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag so your [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge won't work.

*Thanks to [Alexei Levenkov](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272475/gold-duplicate-power-didnt-work/272476?noredirect=1#comment312042_272476) for the update*

Comment: Note: as of 2015-10 new policy in effect - current tags as long as you are not the one who added tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281#268281